# Define global variables as linux commands in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

On Jenkins Pipeline, is there a way to define a global variable as a Linux command (at *****)? As of now, I need to split one variable under `node` (at //*) and the other of the same name under `environment` (at //**). I was trying with the definitions below though they all get errors.

> def SECOND_WORD=sh(script : "echo ${JENKINS_PROJECT_NAME} | cut -d'_' -f2", returnStdout: true).trim()
>
> def SECOND_WORD=sh "echo ${JENKINS_PROJECT_NAME} | cut -d'_' -f2"
>
> def SECOND_WORD=$(echo ${JENKINS_PROJECT_NAME} | cut -d'_' -f2)

```
def JENKINS_PROJECT_NAME="ABC_XYZ-123_QRS"
***** def SECOND_WORD= ??? *****

node('master') {
  stage('Set agent'){
     def SECOND_WORD=sh(script : "echo ${JENKINS_PROJECT_NAME} | cut -d'_' -f2", returnStdout: true).trim() //*
     if (SECOND_WORD ==~ /XYZ.*/) {
        AGENT_LABEL = "master"
     } else {
        AGENT_LABEL = "slave"
     }
   }
}

pipeline {
    agent {
       label "${AGENT_LABEL}"
    }
    environment {
        def SECOND_WORD=sh(script : "echo ${JENKINS_PROJECT_NAME} | cut -d'_' -f2", returnStdout: true).trim() //**
    }
    stages {
        stage('Normal build') {
           steps {
              echo "JENKINS_PROJECT_NAME = ${JENKINS_PROJECT_NAME}"
              echo "SECOND_WORD = ${SECOND_WORD}"
              echo "Running in ${AGENT_LABEL}"
              sh "hostname"
           }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: The matter is how the coding syntax should be at *****. Considering you don't have //* nor //** in the code and replace with ones from the yellow boxes at *****, the first and the second lines got org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MissingContextVariableException: Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing
Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node, and the third line got org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 2: unexpected token: $ @ line 2, column 24.